# Run Nightwatch Tests on Gitlab

Tags: selenium, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nightwatch.js, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new on night-watch and planning to run the night-watch tests on Gitlab whenever i push my code. But I am not getting any right documentation for this and how to setup my .gitlab-ci.yml file. If anybody around has any experience with this?

Answer (score -1):

This post is really old, but I am working on stuff like that right now, so this might help.

First:
You need a gitlab-runner on a server where nightwatch is installed with selenium - IF you want to use this solution (gitlab shell executor)

```
stages:
- deploy

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
    - cd /home/ubuntu/ci_nine/ && nightwatch --env hp venture/incart/
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  when: manual
  only:
  - stage
```